# Font size very small in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have created a website where I had wanted the heading `<h1>` adjust their size along with the width of the `<header>`. I used the `vw` property for this. But the property is not working in firefox as the font size being shown over there is very small.

You can see in this fiddle what I mean. If you run this fiddle in firefox, you will see the small sized fonts.

```css
Body {
  background: white;
  font-family: "Myriad Pro";
  size: 12px;
  color: #323232;
}
header {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 239px;
  min-height: inherit;
  background: #d1d2d4;
  overflow: hidden;
}
header h1 {
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-size-adjust: 0.10;
  font-size: 5vw;
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 13.5%;
  top: 25%;
}
header p {
  font-family: "Myriad Pro";
  font-size-adjust: 0.10;
  font-size: 2vw;
  color: #404041;
  position: absolute;
  left: 13.5%;
  top: 64%;
  letter-spacing: 2pt;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="images/Logo.png" style="margin-left:2.5%; margin-top:2.5%; width:10%; height:inherit;" />
  <h1 style="">Website®</h1>
  <p>Welcome To My Website!</p>
  <img src="http://tinyurl.com/ku6cgpy" style="align: right; float:right; width:40%; height:auto; overflow-style:auto; overflow:visible;" />
</header>
```

[The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z707x908/3/)

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: try `header h1`  remove `font-size-adjust: 0.1`

Comment: Your suggestion works. I want to delete this question. How do I go about doing it?

Comment: Why you want to delete a question? It useful for someone

Comment: I had thought it wasn't such a good question. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `font-size-adjust: 0.1`  from your css

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z707x908/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `font-size-adjust: 0.1` in `header h1`

```css
Body {
  background: white;
  font-family: "Myriad Pro";
  size: 12px;
  color: #323232;
}
header {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 239px;
  min-height: inherit;
  background: #d1d2d4;
  overflow: hidden;
}
header h1 {
  font-family: "Arial";
  
  font-size: 5vw;
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 13.5%;
  top: 25%;
}
header p {
  font-family: "Myriad Pro";
  font-size-adjust: 0.10;
  font-size: 2vw;
  color: #404041;
  position: absolute;
  left: 13.5%;
  top: 64%;
  letter-spacing: 2pt;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="images/Logo.png" style="margin-left:2.5%; margin-top:2.5%; width:10%; height:inherit;" />
  <h1 style="">Website®</h1>
  <p>Welcome To My Website!</p>
  <img src="http://tinyurl.com/ku6cgpy" style="align: right; float:right; width:40%; height:auto; overflow-style:auto; overflow:visible;" />
</header>
```